# Elisp: is this an expected behavior of save-excursion?

Tags: emacs, elisp

The starting condition is this text in `*scratch*`:

```
(
form
30
)

(
   baz
  41
)
```

The whitespace is the only important thing here.
Now, with point on `o` in `form`, evaluating with <kbd>M-:</kbd>(`eval-expression`)
this code:

```
(save-excursion
  (up-list)
  (backward-list)
  (indent-sexp))
```

Gives

```
(
 form
 30
 )
```

with point on `o`. Same (expected) behavior repeats for point on `r`,`m`,`0`,`a`,`z`,`1`.

However for starting point on `f`, `3`, `b`, `4`, the resulting point is one character before
the expected position.

Is this the expected behavior or a bug?
If it's expected, I'd like to know more about rules and edge cases.

### UPD: Add intuitive save-excursion variant

Just in case someone will want it,
here's the behavior that's more intuitive to me (i.e. saves point on `f`, `3` etc.):

```
(defmacro save-excursion-ex (&rest body)
  "More intuitive (`save-excursion' BODY)."
  `(let ((ext (save-match-data
                (looking-back "^\\s-*")))
         (out (save-excursion
                ,@body)))
     (if ext
         (if (or (bolp)
                 (= (point)
                    (save-excursion
                      (back-to-indentation)
                      (point))))
             (back-to-indentation)
           (error "Unexpected")))
     out))
```

Comment: Is this in an `emacs -Q` session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Emacs, the point is considered to be "before" `(point)`. 
So, when `indent-sexp` inserts whitespace, it inserts it *after* the point.
E.g., when you say that the point is on `f`, it is actually at the beginning of line right before `f` and `indent-sexp` inserts spaces *after* it and *before* `f`.

The general rule is that if the point is between the beginning of line and the first non-blank character in the line, it will end up at the beginning of the line, otherwise it will preserve its position relative the surrounding text.

Think of it this way: we indent the code by

1. delete all leading blanks
2. insert leading blanks as necessary

So, the answer is: this is the expected behavior.

More to the implied gist of your question, there is no reason to rely on the specific position of the point after indentation *if* the point was adjacent to whitespace which was normalized.
If you need to get your code working, add a `(goto-char (line-beginning-position))` (or equivalent) after the indentation call and then skip to the position you want to operate on.

Comment: I thought that the invariant is that the point remains on the character that it was on before. That's intuitive. Now I don't see the invariant.

Comment: @abo-abo: there is no such thing as "on character". the point is _between_ characters.

Comment: Fine, but try with `b` in `baz`.
Initially point is between ` ` and `b`.
Finally point is between `^` and ` `.

Comment: the whitespace is normalized. any point position is logically valid.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that.
But consider this: changing initial point `o` to `r` (i.e. by 1) results
it changing the final point by 1.
Same with `r` to `m` again by 1.
But changing `o` to `f` results in -2.

Comment: I finally got it: usually same char, when on leading whitespace - beginning of line.
The example I gave wasn't great. I thought `save-excursion` was a char off, while it was on the
beginning of line. Thanks a lot.